# How to get value inside a div element using JS

Tags: javascript, python, django

Here I have a div element with class med and I want to access the value inside the div of the

Prescribed:{{pro_id.prescribedmed}}

.I tried JS to get the value by using the getattribute() but it does not show. how can get the value of it. Here is the piece of code

```
 <div class="column">
        <!-- style="background-color:#bbb; -->
        <p class="newarrival ">Rs.{{pro_id.price}}</p>
        <h4>{{pro_id.name}}</h4>
        <p><strong>Category:</strong> {{ pro_id.category}}</p>
        <p><strong>Description:</strong> {{pro_id.smalldescription}}.</p>
        <div class="med hidden" >
            <p>Prescribed:{{pro_id.prescribedmed}}</p>
        </div>
        <button data-product={{pro_id.id}} data-action="add" type="button" class="btn-cart update-cart"> Add to cart
       </button>
    </div>
```

i tired to get the element like

```
var premed = document.getElementsByClassName('med').innerText;
console.log(premed)
```

here the output gives like undefined

Comment: just paste your raw code here, I'll edit the post.

Comment: post your JavaScript too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```
<p class="med_prescribed">Prescribed: {{ pro_id.prescribedmed }}</p>
```

in your JS as follows

```
var premed = document.getElementsByClassName('med_prescribed')[0].innerText;
console.log(premed);
```

Comment: I tried this and the output while doing console.log is undefined

Comment: can you see the ```pro_id.prescribedmed```'s value in rendered HTML?

Comment: yes the value is actually boolean and it show the value in the rendered HTML

Answer (score 1):

If I had to do that it would look next:
First select the element with `Document.querySelector()`.
Then extract the text of the element.
And finally use the `String.prototype.substring()` method to get the needed value.

Answer (score 1):

You cant get the attribute because you dont have one.

Div element:

```
<div class="med hidden" id="Div_id" value="Value_here" >
```

JS:

```
var value = document.getElementById("Div_id").getAttribute ("value")
```

Comment: You can put code by indenting it with 4 spaces, or alternatively putting it inside triple backticks `\`\`\`code here\`\`\`` or if inline use single backticks: `\`inline code\``